# Use a single GiST index or two B-tree indices for geo-location queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm working on a project with a database that holds geo-location data. Each point of data is associated with both a longitude and a latitude and I need to make it so that when a user sends a query with a latitude and longitude from clicking a map the database retrieves all points within a set distance from that location and the server responds with the data.

My first thoughts were to use two different B-tree indices, one for latitude and another longitude, calculate max and min values for latitude and longitude based on the desired distance and select points from the database that fall within these max and min values. Recently, however, I read about GiST indexes from the docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-types.html) and from what I can gather this seems like the type of query it was designed for but I don't know if there'd be a significant improvement in performance or not. Should I use the GiST index for this or stay with the original idea of using two B-tree indices?

Comment: Why aren't you using PostGIS?

Comment: @rd_nielsen Never heard about it before. Will look into it though. Thanks!